# ListView Not Showing Data

Tags: javascript, windows-8, expression-blend, windows-store-apps

I'm following the tutorial at the beginning of [Building Windows 8 Apps with JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321861280). My ListView is simply not showing the data, and I'm not sure where to turn. It looks like it's simple and easy, but I must be missing something. When I run the app (or view it in Blend), **I see everything but the ListView data. Any idea what I'm missing?**

**This is the result:**

[image]

**This is the HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="fragment homepage">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle">Bob's RSS Reader</span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <div>List of feeds:</div>
            <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemDataSource:feeds.dataSource}"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

**And this is the home.js file:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    window.feeds = [
        { title: "Brandon Satrom",
            url: "http://feeds.feedburner.com/userinexperience/tYGT" },
        { title: "Chris Sells",
            url: "http://sellsbrothers.com/posts/?format=rss" },
        { title: "Channel 9",
            url: "http://channel9.msdn.com/Feeds/RSS" },
    ];

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {

        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Where is your ItemTemplate for the ListView? Without an ItemTemplate, I don't think the ListView will render output properly.

Comment: @devhammer I didn't get to that part yet. I'm not worried about it rendering properly; I just want to see something, like in the example. The template is next... In fact, it does render with my answer shown below (just not correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx). This solution creates a namespace to make the data publicly available. While, this works, I don't understand why my original code didn't work. I thought that window.feeds would be available to the HTML... guess not.

HTML:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemDataSource: DataExample.itemList.dataSource}"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var dataArray = [
        { title: "Brandon Satrom",
            url: "http://feeds.feedburner.com/userinexperience/tYGT" },
        { title: "Chris Sells",
            url: "http://sellsbrothers.com/posts/?format=rss" },
        { title: "Channel 9",
            url: "http://channel9.msdn.com/Feeds/RSS" },
    ];

    var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);

    // Create a namespace to make the data publicly accessible. 
    var publicMembers =
    {
        itemList: dataList
    };

    WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", publicMembers);

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {

        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it isn't working is due to you not setting it to a Binding List. A normal javascript array does not contain a dataSource property. Also, don't forget to use the 'new' keyword. I forgot and spent a fair amount of time trying to figure out why it was failing.

```
window.feeds = new WinJS.Binding.List([
        { title: "Brandon Satrom",
            url: "http://feeds.feedburner.com/userinexperience/tYGT" },
        { title: "Chris Sells",
            url: "http://sellsbrothers.com/posts/?format=rss" },
        { title: "Channel 9",
            url: "http://channel9.msdn.com/Feeds/RSS" },
    ]);
```